# How can I get a message box to appear every time I left-click in a window?

Tags: winapi, window

I want to open a message box with the word "left" when I left click the mouse.

So I used wndproc and MK_LBUTTON, but the wndproc function wrote the code, but the WinMain part doesn't know how to write the code.

I don't want to open a window, but when I searched on Google, I only have a code example that only shows a window.
(Opening the window did not solve the problem ..)

What should I do? Help
(If you've written as much as possible but don't understand the question, please ask me and I'll answer it.

And I'm not good at English, so I wrote a translator.)

## my code(try)

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance
, LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{
    //???
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT iMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (iMessage) {
    case MK_LBUTTON:
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("left"),TEXT("message"), MB_OK);
    }
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, iMessage, wParam, lParam));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MK_LBUTTON` is not a message, you need to catch [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown), `WM_LBUTTONUP` or `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`.

These messages are only sent to the active window where the mouse is clicked. If you want to catch clicks on all windows then you need to use a [mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) and [pump messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues).